# Problems with new command multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn

I am trying to make a new command that creates a multicolumn table based on two parameters given:
My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand\dummy[2]{\multicolumn{\the \numexpr #2 - #1 + 1}{c}{hola}}


\begin{document}

This is an example of \dummy{4}{5}

\end{document}
```

However, I have the following errors:

```
 Misplaced \omit. [This is a example of \dummy{4}{5}]
 Misplaced \span. [This is a example of \dummy{4}{5}]
 Misplaced \omit. [This is a example of \dummy{4}{5}]
```

Can anyone help me with these please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `\multicolumn` must be inside a `tabular` environment with *at least* the same number of columns as the `\multicolumn`.

Comment: Might seem dumb, but can you give the MWE with the proposed modification? How do you know forehand how many columns would be if it depends of the parameters?

Comment: Please, read some basic information about tables in LaTeX (environment `tabular`, ...) and clarify your question. Neither creates `\multicolumn` a table nor are the parameters of `\dummy`and the purpose of `\dummy` explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\omit` and `\span` commands that appear in the error are TeX primitives for controlling alignment environments, like `tabular`, and you cannot use these commands outside an alignment environment.

The `\multicolumn` command uses `\omit` and `\span` internally to make its thing so, consequently, you cannot use the `\multicolumn` outside an alignment.

To fix the issue you can wrap your `\dummy` command in a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\dummy[2]{\multicolumn{\numexpr(#2)-(#1)+1\relax}{c}{hola}}

\begin{document}

This is an example of
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \dummy{4}{5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Notice that I used two columns (`{cc}`) after the `\begin{tabular}`, because `#2 - #1 + 1 = 5 - 4 + 1 = 2`. You'll need at least the same number of columns for the tabular as the number of columns given to `\multicolumn`.

---

Also, as egreg noted, the `\the` isn't necessary there. `\the` is used for printing the contents of a box, dimen, count (and the list goes on). In this case, the value returned by `\numexpr` is enough.

---

Also², as Heiko Oberdiek noted, enclosing `#1` and `#2` in parentheses make the code more robust in case there are expressions in the arguments to `\dummy`.

Comment: I guess that `\the` can be omitted.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, I didn't notice that. Thanks :)

Comment: If `#1` and/or `#2` contain formulas, `\numexpr(#2)-(#1)+1\relax` is robuster.